# How can a web site know my gmail address?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I was on a random web site that I had never been on , and they knew I was logged on to gmail and what my email was.

Is this legal?  Is this just part of the Google API?

I was going to leave an anonymous comment here:

http://www.corporateofficeheadquarters.com/2012/05/nysc-corporate-office-headquarters.html#comment-form

and my gmail popped up.

Answer (score 2):

This site is hosted on [Blogger](https://www.blogger.com/home).

Blogger is a Google service/domain.

Comment: They have different domains and different origins.   Cookies and local storage are based on domains.  Maybe they are using environment things like - mac address, ip address to correlate who I am.